# Get charge state remotely

Tags: charging, remote-access

I want my desktop to check state of the phone and warn me at appropriate time (calculated on my presence at the desktop, phone charge, time of day and other criteria).

Is there a way to get my phone charge state remotely? What software/services should I use?

As programmer, I'd prefer a solution that would allow to script criteria and logic myself. All I need are means to access charge state remotely say through Google API's or web-published information.

I'm asking this question here as I believe there should be a ton of monitoring Android applications publishing state by various means.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's an app here that allows you to do that according to the description (along with many more things): https://market.android.com/details?id=com.androidlost&hl=en

If you want to code your own application then you'll want to check out this Intent and the two Intents below it (ACTION_BATTERY_LOW, ACTION_BATTERY_OKAY):
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED

And this class which has what the Intent contains: 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/BatteryManager.html

You could have your application pick up the ACTION_BATTERY_LOW Intent and then send a message to you warning you about the status.

I'm assuming you've done some Android development before, if not then get the basics down before coming back and trying to code your battery app.

Comment: Is this still possible?  [This page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Battery_Status_API) says the Web API is obsolete.  Or, is there an alternative web-based API for checking Android battery status?

Comment: The APIs I mention are native Android APIs not web APIs, you'd be better off asking on SO about that but off the top of my head I think they took away the battery APIs because of privacy concerns and doubt they'll be coming back, how many websites really need to see how much battery you've got..?

Comment: Very true - although there's many more ways GPS location could be abused by others than battery level... but people (myself included) don't want to give up the advantages of sharing location with websites (which was a tough decision for me!)